# SqlAlchemy querying deep nested objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, nested

I need help with querying model to get deeper relatonship. 
Animals is a main table. It should easly load imgs and stories and its pretty simple. But AnimalsStories has own imgs in same AnimalsImgs table. AnimalsImgs has imgs for both classes Animals and AnimalsStories and both classes have relationships with it.
So i should be able to load all Animals and their stories in AnimalsStories and then from this class i should be able to use .img attrubute which reffers to AnimalsImgs and holds imgs for stories. SqlAlchemy say that it is possible with subqueryload. And it is. But only two levels down. AnimalsStories.img never load.

```
class Animals(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'animals'
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    imgs = db.relationship("AnimalsImgs", backref=db.backref('animals',lazy=False))
    stories= db.relationship("AnimalsStories",lazy='joined')

class AnimalsImgs(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'animals_imgs'
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True,autoincrement='auto')
    id_animal = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('animals.id'),nullable=False)

class AnimalsStories(db.Model):
    __tablename__='animals_stories'
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    id_animal= db.Column(db.BigInteger,db.ForeignKey('animals.id'), nullable=False)
    id_animal_img = db.Column(db.BigInteger,db.ForeignKey('animals_imgs.id'))
    img=db.relationship("AnimalsImgs", uselist=False)
```

I've tried something like this :

```
    query = Animals.query.options(subqueryload(Animals.stories).subqueryload(AnimalsStories.img))
    result = query.all()
    print(result)
    for res in result:
        print(res.rescue.img)
```

And ended with " AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'img' "
It should be pretty simple to query deeper objects. I think the problem is somewhere in models structures.

Edit #1 
I've ended up with solution. It was not that hard.
Animals reffers to stories as one to many. Stories reffers to Imgs as one to one. So with query i posted (with subqueryload) it can be done by:

```py
    query = Animals.query.options(subqueryload(Animals.stories).subqueryload(AnimalsStories.img))
    result = query.all()

    print(result)
    for res in result:
        print(res.stories)
        for r in res.stories: # stories appears as array so they are iterable
            print(r.img)
```

And it prints all the levels pretty clear.

It can be done as well, maybe even better, with join. We are sure that result  doesnt have any missing or empty arrays.

```py
 query = Animals.query.join(AnimalsStories).join(AnimalsImgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure which types of relationship you want to model. I made the following assumptions:

- A image can have a relationship to one or no animal, as well to one or no story
- A story has a relationship to one animal, as well as to none or several images
- A animal can have relationships to none or several images, as well to none or several stories

This would lead to a model like this:

```
class Animals(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'animals'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  imgs = db.relationship("AnimalsImgs", backref=db.backref('animals'),lazy=True)
  stories= db.relationship("AnimalsStories", backref=db.backref('animals'), 
    lazy=True)

class AnimalsImgs(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'animals_imgs'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  id_animal = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('animals.id'),nullable=True)
  id_animal_story = 
     db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('animals_stories.id'),nullable=True)

class AnimalsStories(db.Model):
  __tablename__='animals_stories'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  id_animal= db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('animals.id'), nullable=False)
  imgs=db.relationship("AnimalsImgs", backref=db.backref('stories'),lazy=True)
```

Now I have added the following scenrios:

1. An animal a1 that has a relationship to an image ai1 and to an story ast1. (but not relationship between the story and the image.
2. An animal a2 that has a relationship to story ast2. Ast2 has a relationship to a image ai2. But no relationship betwenn ast2 and a2.
3. An animal a3 that has a relationship to a story ast3 and a image ai3. ai3 has also a relationship to ast3.

Code sample like this:

```
  a1 = Animals()
  a2 = Animals()
  a3 = Animals ()
  a4 = Animals ()
  db.session.add(a1)
  db.session.add(a2)    
  db.session.add(a3)
  db.session.add(a4)
  ai1 = AnimalsImgs(animals = a1)
  db.session.add(ai1)
  ast1 = AnimalsStories(animals = a1)
  db.session.add(ast1)       
  ast2 = AnimalsStories(animals = a2)
  db.session.add(ast2)    
  ai2 = AnimalsImgs(stories = ast2)
  db.session.add(ai2)    
  ast3 = AnimalsStories(animals = a3)
  db.session.add(ast3)  
  ai3 = AnimalsImgs(animals = a3, stories = ast3)
  db.session.add(ai3)
```

If you want to query all images that are connected to stories, you can use:

```
  animalimages_ofallstories_ofalanimals = 
      AnimalsImgs.query.join(AnimalsStories).join(Animals).all()
```

You get image ai2 and ai3 as result. (ai1 is not connected to a story but only to an animal)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But  my thought was to dump it later with marshmallow and end up with something like that object :
{
(animal)id, 
...
stories:[
  {id,text,img:{id,file_name}},...stories...}
]
}

How can i archive this ?

// It was natural for me to start with query something like : Animal.query.join(AnimalsStories).join(AnimalsImgs).all(). Started with animal, get its stories and for every story get img, but i cant get that third level img object couse of an error AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'img'.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. AnimalsImgs.query.join(AnimalsStories).join(Animals).all() can deliver you what you want to get. If the final result of your join-based query is a AnimalsImgs, you can start with this object in the query, and then join the other tables. Just as you described above, but only in the other direction. Logically, it is "Started with animal, get its stories and for every story get img" but just written the other direction in the query.

Comment: When you generate your archive sequence, you need to determine the images belonging to a given story, i.e. you need to add a filter to the join query.